# All my desktop documents and some of the shortcuts have disappeared on Windows Vista

Tags: windows-vista, desktop

I have no idea what happened ... but all documents on my desktop disappeared.  Some program icons too ... it's very puzzling... I am sure I have not deleted them ...

Can anyone help?

Thanks

Edit 1: I found what happened by searching for my documents on disk: somehow (mouse error?) the Desktop Folder was dragged and dropped or to another folder ... Now it appears that Desktop has changed it's default location... how to fix that??

Comment: What happens when you drag it back to its' proper location?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right click on the Desktop folder in the new location, select **Properties** open the Location Tab and click **Move**, now pick the new location and click **Apply** as indicated in this answer [here](https://superuser.com/questions/79604/how-to-change-default-desktop-folder-location-on-windows-vista/79623#79623)

Answer (score 0):

Desktop should be under C:\Users\%username%\

You could drag and drop it to there, and try restarting your computer (or just restarting explorer.exe).